# Dependency issues: Could not load file or assembly... or one of it's dependenceis. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, vb.net, dependency-properties

I'm running into a bit of a strange issue. I have a Visual Studio solution with two projects in it. The two solutions are different languages, VB and C#. I recently learned that you can reference different projects, even if they are different languages, just as long as they're all .NET projects. This is very convenient as I'm basically making a plugin wrapper for a Windows Form project to be used as a plugin in another program. However, I'm running into a dependency issue while running the plugin within the host application.

Here's where things get weird. The original Windows form program (the one written in VB) is not written by me, however, if it's compiled to an EXE, it runs perfectly fine. However, I compiled it as a class into a DLL so I could reference methods from the plugin wrapper, written in C#. The plugin will work perfectly fine up until it attempts to call a method in the VB project.

I have the C# project referencing the VB project through the reference manager and the reference within the References folder set to "Copy Local" to have it copy the compiled DLL from the VB project with the plugin when it is compiled by Visual Studio.

What I am baffled by is the fact that independently, both of these projects function perfectly (in the sense that the plugin will not crash until it attempts to access methods from the other project), but as soon as I try to reference one from the other, everything falls apart. Am I missing something really simple?

Comment: Inspect the exception and figure out which file is actually missing. This might be a native DLL, for example. And of course, make sure that all the required files are available.

Comment: You have verified the dependency is being copied to your application Bin? It sounds like one of your project is referencing a dependency that is not in your main application.

Comment: I've made sure that all DLLs that I'm referencing within the project are set to "Copy always" (at least, all of the external dlls that contain a couple of APIs that we are using) and have verified that they are all getting copied to the final output folder of the plugin to no avail...